# Removing a value in a multiple field

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

I have in the user there is a multi field in which links are stored. How can I delete only one? (ex. *link1*).

This is what it looks like in the database:
[image]

I get the list from the user like this:

```
$clientId = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load('28');
$clientId = $clientId->get('field_links')->getValue();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ItemList::removeItem()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21TypedData%21Plugin%21DataType%21ItemList.php/function/ItemList%3A%3AremoveItem/9.1.x) like this:

```php
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load('28');
$field = $user->get('field_links');
$field_values = $field->getValue();

// Find the key of the link whose title is 'link1'
$key = array_search('link1', array_column($field_values, 'title'));  
if ($key) {
  // Remove that link
  $field->removeItem($key);
  // Save the user
  $user->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$items = $clientId->get('field_links');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
if ($items->get($i)->value == 1) {
    $items->removeItem($i);
    $i--;
}
}
$clientId->save();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).